# How to initialize a Stripe Connect Express session for user to create a Stripe account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

So I am trying to use Stripe Connect with Express accounts. I've had a look at the documentation located [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts). I am having some trouble getting started. I've been able to use Stripe Checkout without a problem, but I'm not able to redirect a user to Stripe so they can create an account to sell on my platform. I've been playing around with it, and this is the code that I have so far:

```
export const sellerOnboard = async () => {
  try {
    await stripe.accounts.create({
      type: 'express'
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

sellerOnboard gets called when some text gets pressed on the front end, but nothing happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an Account Link and redirect them to it so they can finish onboarding: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link

Comment: Holy. Crap. It's actually WORKING! Holy mother of GOD. Setting up an online marketplace has been a coding goal of mine since back in 2015, before I knew how to do anything. Today, it actually happened! Much thanks to you, and to everyone at Stripe who I have harassed to no end with stupid questions over IRC, Twitter and other platforms. Tears of happiness are welling up in my eyes as I write this. This is amazing.

Comment: Awesome - congrats, and you're very welcome! :)